# Find an Array Value using Two Variables

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose I set up a simple array:

```
var list = [
    "Hello",
    "Goodbye",
];
```

And then I set two variables, one to specify two variables: one for the name of the array, and another for the number, as such:

```
var array = "list";
var number = 0;
```

And then I run the following command:

```
console.log(array[number]);
```

But it outputs the number "1" instead of "Hello".

Can somebody explain this?

EDIT:

I wrote this question as an inexperienced programmer. What I should have used to complete the task was a dictionary.

They will allow you to, very roughly speaking, index arrays with strings.

Comment: Why do you do `var array = "list";`?

Comment: You must referance the current scope. If that is global then you would use `console.log(window[array][number])` as window is the global scope.

Comment: @Blindman67 That can be done, but not recommended. And, from the variable name in `var array = "list";` you can get idea what OP want to do here.

Comment: @Tushar  I would guess he is trying to indirectly referance the array `list`. Using bracket notation is a legitimate method to access variables, `this[array][number]` would have worked as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But it outputs the number "1" instead of "Hello". Any ideas?

No, it doesn't output `1`, it's `l`(the alphabet `L` lowercased).

`array` is no longer an array when you assign a **string** `list` to it in

```
var array = "list";
```

and then

```
array[0]
```

is equivalent of

```
"list"[0]
```

which will return the character at zeroth index, thus returning `l`.

---

**Solution:**

To reference an array, use the variable name(**no quotes required**)

```
var array = list; // Remove quotes.
```

If you don't want to reference same array and want **to create a copy**, use `slice()`

```
var copy = list.slice(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it is outputting "1" (number one) and not "l" (lowecase letter ell)?  Because

```
console.log(array[number]);
```

starts with the `array` object (which is a string of value 'list')  and then returns the position associated with `number`, which is `0`.  So in english this means print the `0`th letter of 'list' which is 'l'.

Based upon what you wrote, is sounds like you are being very abstract with a level of indirection I don't normally see.  You can do what you are asking, but it is a strange thing to do.  `list` is a variable on the global scope, which for a browser is available through the `window`. So you could do the following:

```
window[array][number]
```

which is interpreted to the following:

```
window['list'][number]
```

which is the same as

```
list[number]
```

which is the same as

```
list[0]
```

which is

```
"Hello"
```

Generally, the level of abstraction you specify with the `array` variable is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(array[number])
```

is printing out the value of the 0th element of the string "list" which is l, which is what you're seeing.

You have assigned the string "list" the a variable named array. And then when you attempt to retrieve the 0th (you variable number) element, you get the first character in the string "list".